# ヘルプページ 「検索の方法は？」で一部の記号が正常に表示されていない

Tags: バグ, 完了, ヘルプ

[検索の方法は？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/searching) の「ワイルドカード」に関する説明部分で、一部の`*`が消えてしまっています。

**現在の表示**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**英語版の内容**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: MSE にも報告済みです。 - [Some symbols are not displayed correctly on the help page "How do I search?" on an international site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351408)

Answer (score 4):

今日の時点では、アスタリスク`*`が正常に表示されております。どこかのタイミングで修正されたようです。ご報告ありがとうございました。

[image: アスタリスク]